# how to convert char to string

Tags: java, string, char, jbutton

I have a word as string that want to take a character of it and assign it as the button name. As you know button only accepts String.

```
    String possibleLetters = "asdaAsadWERWasdas";
    for (int i = 0; i <= possibleLetters.length(); i++)
        {
            String bottonName = possibleLetters.charAt(i);
            JButton letterBottons = new JButton(bottonName);

        }
```

Comment: Umm. Don't see a problem here -- `charAt` [returns a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt), so indeed you get a number of buttons. Some with same names, but then again, that *seems* to be what you want.

Comment: @Jongware thanks but Char at doesn't return a String, returns a char.

Comment: @jongware I'm pretty sure [String#charAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) returns char...

Comment: the link to String.charAt says it returns a char

Comment: @Jongware - Java and Javascript are different languages.  You are looking at the Javascript API spec for String.

Comment: @StephenC: ouch. Probably not the last time I'll make that mistake!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
JButton letterBottons = new JButton(Character.toString(bottonName));
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is:

```
String possibleLetters = "asdaAsadWERWasdas";
for (int i = 0; i <= possibleLetters.length(); i++) {
    String buttonName = possibleLetters.substring(i, i + 1);
    JButton letterButtons = new JButton(buttonName);
}
```

Depending on the implementation<sup>1</sup> of the `String` class, this might give you *marginally* better performance.

---

<sup>1 - In older versions of Java, the `substring` method would create a `String` object that shared its backing array with the original one.  By constrast the `Character.toString()` method creates a string with its own (newly allocated) backing array.  This changes in Java 7.  Now the `substring` creates a String that does NOT share its backing array.  This neatly illustrates why this level of micro-optimization can be a waste of time in the long term.</sup>